# python pandas как получить индекс первого не подходящего под условия значения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, временные-ряды

```
import pandas as pd

# assign data
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'value_1': [4, 1, 7, 2, 3, 0, 10, 1, 9],
                       'value_2': [6, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 2, 3]})
#                                        ^--> индекс данного первого значения не удовлетворяющего условию
print(df_new)

# фильтруем данные по колонке 'value_2'
dFilter = df_new[df_new.value_2 > 4]
dFilter
```

В моем примере это будет значение '4' в столбце df_new.value_2  c индексом = 2 !

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [python pandas как лучше отфильтровать данные dataframe до первого найденного значения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1535169/python-pandas-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-dataframe-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: вопрос похож , но здесь необходимо получить/найти индекс значения, а не dataframe

Comment: в ответах на первичный вопрос есть и про получение индекса - см. "Либо через локатор и индекс:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
idx = df_new["value_2"].le(4).idxmax()
```

сначала получаете булеву серию, где индексы со значениями, удовлетворяющими условию, будут True. Остальные, соответственно - False. idxmax выведет индекс *первого* максимального значения (True).

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы получить индекс первого значения в столбце value_2 которое не удовлетворяет условию (value_2 > 4), вы можете воспользоваться методом idxmax(). Этот метод вернет индекс первого максимального значения в серии, соответствующего заданному условию. Вот как это можно сделать:

```
import pandas as pd

# assign data
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'value_1': [4, 1, 7, 2, 3, 0, 10, 1, 9],
                       'value_2': [6, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 2, 3]})

# фильтруем данные по колонке 'value_2'
dFilter = df_new[df_new.value_2 > 4]

# Получаем индекс первого не удовлетворяющего условию значения
index_first_non_matching = dFilter.index[0]
print("Индекс первого не удовлетворяющего условию значения:", index_first_non_matching)
```

В этом коде, dFilter.index[0] вернет индекс первой строки в датафрейме dFilter, которая не удовлетворяет условию value_2 > 4, так как строки в Pandas датафреймах индексируются с нуля.
Надеюсь получится у вас

Comment: но ваше решение показало индекс = 0 , где находится соответственно значение '6' > '4' ; а мне необходим индекс наоборот значения не подходящего под условие

Comment: тогда попробуйте !>

Comment: import pandas as pd

# assign data
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'value_1': [4, 1, 7, 2, 3, 0, 10, 1, 9],
                       'value_2': [6, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 2, 3]})

# фильтруем данные по колонке 'value_2'
dFilter = df_new[df_new.value_2 <= 4]

# Получаем индекс первого не удовлетворяющего условию значения
index_first_non_matching = dFilter.index[0]
print("Индекс первого не удовлетворяющего условию значения:", index_first_non_matching)